# Seaborn Heatmap Remove Scientific Notation

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I've read dozens of pages/posts on how to prevent seaborn heatmap from showing scientific notation but they are all about avoiding it in the annotations.  I've tried to implement that but no matter what I try the heatmap wants to give me scientific notation.  The count I'm trying to display is in the millions which maybe is why it wants to display in scientific notation but that is not what I want.  Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: You can change the colorbar tick formatting via `sns.heatmap(..., cbar_kws={'format': '%.0f'})`.  When posting on StackOverflow, please add minimal reproducible code and data in text format, not as an image.

Comment: this is indeed the solution, thank you SO MUCH!!

Comment: any chance you know how to add commas into larger numbers?

Comment: I've followed the documentation all the way to this dead end but it doesn't explain the format options at all.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter

Comment: Matplotlib uses of few different ways for the formatting, which is indeed confusing. Here `cbar_kws={'format': lambda x, pos:f'{x:,.0f}'}` seems to work.